# Continuar após execute() terminado

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma class com o nome `Request_Login` que valida os dados de login com o servidor e uma string `LOGIN_RESPONSE` que armazena a resposta do servidor.

Quando os dados são submetidos no formulário e é pressionado `enter` é executado o seguinte código:

```
// VALIDATE LOGIN
new Request_Login().execute();

if(LOGIN_RESPONSE.equals("true")){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login efectuado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login sem sucesso.\nValide os seus dados e tente novamente.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Classe Request_Login:

```
class Request_Login extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... string) {

        String RETRIEVED_CONTENT = "";

        InputStream inputStream;

        try {
            // New HTTP Object
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // Build POST Array
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", user_input.toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass_input.toString()));

            // New POST Object
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(DOMAIN+SYS_PATH+file);


            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            inputStream = entity.getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            RETRIEVED_CONTENT = sb.toString();

            Log.d("HTTP", "HTTP: OK");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("HTTP", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        LOGIN_RESPONSE = RETRIEVED_CONTENT;
        Log.i("RETRIEVED_CONTENT", RETRIEVED_CONTENT);
        return RETRIEVED_CONTENT;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "Por favor aguarde...","Validando dados de login.", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }



}
```

O problema é que esse código está a devolver um erro `java.lang.NullPointerException` na variável `LOGIN_RESPONSE` o que significa que estou a fazer a validação `if(LOGIN_RESPONSE.equals("true"))` antes dela armazenar a resposta no final da execução de `new Request_Login().execute();`.

Como posso fazer para apenas fazer a validação da variável `LOGIN_RESPONSE` após terminar a execução da classe `Request_Login`?

Comment: Se possível, coloque também a classe `Request_Login` para ajudar na resposta. Esta classe é uma extensão de `AsyncTask`?

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1911/101

Comment: @PauloRodrigues acrescentei a classe Request_Login

Answer (score 1):

Sendo esta uma requisição assíncrona, a resposta que você vai obter é ao final do ciclo, e como bem você disse, logo após o `execute()` você não vai obter o resultado imediatamente.

O final do ciclo e a resposta que você espera acontece no método `onPostExecute`, então você pode fazer diretamente nele. Se o *toast* for sua única ação, fica mais fácil assim:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    progressDialog.dismiss();

    if (result.equals("true")) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Login efectuado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Login sem sucesso.\nValide os seus dados e tente novamente.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

O **context** você pode passar no construtor da classe e armazenar em uma variável privada.

Este é o método mais simples, mas você pode também criar uma **interface** para ser o seu *listener* e implementar junto da sua classe `Request_Login` e ficar "escutando" a resposta na própria `Activity`. Fica a seu critério.